# Promise all that handles all catch but still continue

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to find a way to make Promise.All with 2 promises but in case 1 is 200 I want to use the data.

The reason I want to use Promise.All is because I want to wait for all the responses together.

this is my code

```
    try {
    //try {
      const firstAPIRes = await this.firstAPI();
      const secondAPIRes = await this.secondAPI();
    //} catch (err) {
    //  console.log(err);
    //}
    responses = [];
    Promise.allSettled([
      firstAPIRes,
      secondAPIRes
    ]).then(function(results) {
      results.forEach(function(pi, index) {
        if (pi.isFulfilled()) {
          console.log('p[' + index + '] is fulfilled with value = ', pi.value());
          this.responses[index] = pi.value();
        } else {
          console.log('p[' + index + '] is rejected with reason = ', pi.reason());
          this.responses[index] = pi.reason();
        }
      });
    });

  // reasons is empty...
 } catch (err) {
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting 404 in one of them, and it takes me automatically to the catch.

the allSettled doesnt init the responses.

I want to be able to use the data even if one of the promises fails, and of course, I want to know which one failed.

What is the way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: look into `Promise.allSettled` - each result will have a status of `fulfilled` or `rejected` ... and a `value` for the former, and a `reason` for the latter

Comment: @Bravo looked already. the problem is that it doesn't even get there. the promise throws an error before. (in the //** fails here!**)

Comment: then don't await those promises! `Promise.allSettled([this.firstAPI(), his.secondAPI()])` - I only mentioned `Promise.allSettled` because you were not using it, nor did you mention it ... I have no idea what `Promise.settle` is though - is that something you made up?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `await`, and `Promise.allSettled`. That's not going to work, because `await` is really waiting for your response, and if it fails, it throws and never reaches whatever you are trying to do. So there are two ways:

```
const firstAPIRes = await this.firstAPI().catch();
const secondAPIRes = await this.secondAPI().catch();
```

This ignores any errors and will run the API's sequentially. If you want to run them parallel, you can do the following:

```
const responses = await Promise.allSettled([
  this.firstApi(),
  this.secondApi()
]);

this.responses = responses.map((response) => response.isFulfilled()
  ? response.value()
  : response.reason()
);
```